# How to add pep257 to flycheck?

Tags: flycheck

I use flycheck for Python with pylint, pep8 and other built-in checkers, but also I will use pep257 to highlight doc-comments formatting errors. I read official documentation, but not understand, who I must write in my .emacs for connecting pep257 to flycheck.

How to add pep257 to flycheck without opening issue on GutHub?

Comment: I think that you could just `pip install flake8-pep257` to automatically include PEP 257 warnings in `flake8`.  You'd have to use `flake8` as syntax checker instead of `pylon` then, obviously.

Comment: Thanks! It's work from command line fine.
But in EMACS flycheck crashes with message "Checker python-flake8 returned non-zero exit code 1, but no errors from output". How to fix this error?

Comment: That's a bug in Flycheck then.  Please open an issue on GitHub, providing your Emacs and Flycheck version, your flake8 version and all relevant details 

Comment: Thank you for help! I will check your answer as valid, if you write comment with "flake8-pep257" as answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, flake8-pep257 has a bug that prevents it from working with Flycheck.  See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could just `pip install flake8-pep257` to automatically include PEP 257 warnings in `flake8`. You'd have to use `flake8` as syntax checker instead of `pylint` then, obviously.

Note, though, that there's [a bug in flake8-pep257](https://github.com/Robpol86/flake8-pep257/issues/2) which prevents it from reading from standard input.  This prevents pep257 from working with Flycheck currently.